# How do I get the response text from a treq request?

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, twisted, treq

I am trying to get started with some example code of the treq library, to little avail. While it is easy to get the status code and a few other properties of the response to the request, getting the actual text of the response is a little more difficult. The print_response function available in this example code is not present in the version that I have:

```
from twisted.internet.task import react
from _utils import print_response

import treq


def main(reactor, *args):
    d = treq.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
    d.addCallback(print_response)
    return d

react(main, [])
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from _utils import print_response
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_utils'
```

I am not really sure where to go from here...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you importing from the private module `_utils`?

Comment: @Stephen Rauch I am just trying to make the example code work. The module was provided in the treq library and allegedly contains some function named print_response that every example I can find uses to print the response text. It seemed odd to me as well, but it's all I can find.

Comment: The traceback you show does not match your code. Your line 2 is `from treq import get`, which can't throw the import error of `print_response`

Comment: Apologies...I have edited the post to show the correct code and traceback. This just tells me that it can't find the module, which is why I attempted to import from treq._utils (and forgot to reflect that in the original post).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that I look at it, that example is extremely bad, especially if you're new to twisted. Please give this a try:

```
import treq
from twisted.internet import defer, task

def main(reactor):
    d = treq.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
    d.addCallback(print_results)
    return d

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def print_results(response):
    content = yield response.content()
    text = yield response.text()
    json = yield response.json()

    print(content)  # raw content in bytes
    print(text)     # encoded text
    print(json)     # JSON

task.react(main)
```

The only thing you really have to know is that the `.content()`,`.text()`,`.json()` return `Deferred` objects that eventually return the body of the response. For this reason, you need to `yield` or execute callbacks.

Let's say you only want the text content, you could this:

```
def main(reactor):
    d = treq.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
    d.addCallback(treq.text_content)
    d.addCallback(print)    # replace print with your own callback function
    return d
```

The `treq.content()` line of functions make it easy to return only the content, if thats all you care about, and do stuff with it.

Comment: Thank you for providing a working example. This is exactly what I need to continue.